# if T and S are two normal operators on real inner product space also T ans S commute .Is TS normal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know result is true for complex inner product space because we can diagonalize Tand S. but in real inner product space T and S cannot be diagonalized.then is this result true ?how I proceed I don not know. Give met any hint

Answer (score 2):

This is true for finite dimensional inner product spaces.  On such spaces, we note that for normal operators, $ST = TS \implies ST^* = T^*S$, as proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675239/ab-ba-implies-abt-bta/675267#675267).

I'm not sure whether this is the case for arbitrary Hilbert spaces.

Comment: To prove this I need TS^*=ST^*

Comment: If that is the case, you could use [this result](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675239/ab-ba-implies-abt-bta/675267#675267).  Note that while the statement uses diagonalizations over the complex numbers, it holds for any normal operators on a real (finite dimensional) inner product space.

Comment: this case is not given can you suggest me that if ST=TS then IS ST^*=TS^*

Comment: "This case is not given": do you mean that the space might be infinite-dimensional?

Comment: But normal operator on real inner product space may not have any non zero characterstic vectors

Comment: space is finite dimensional

Comment: If $ST$ is normal as an operator over a complex inner-product space, then it is certainly normal as an operator over the restricted real inner-product space.  If you want an approach that doesn't **use** the complex extension to the real space, then that is another matter.