# Prove that $N$ normal and $TN=NT$ implies $T^*N=NT^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $T,N:V\to V$ such that $N$ is a normal operator and $TN=NT$.
>   Prove that $T^*N=NT^*$ and $N^*T=TN^*$.

I'd be glad for help because I don't even have an idea how to approach this

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/675239/81360). I'm hesitant to call this a duplicate, though.

Comment: Look up "Fuglede's theorem" in any book on advanced linear algebra.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** As a consequence of the spectral theorem, there exists a polynomial $p(t)$ such that $N^* = p(N)$.