# Q. Normal operator and properties

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, normal-families

Let $V$ be finite space and $T$ and $S$ normal operator supose $TS=ST$, prove that $S+T$ and $ST$ are normal.

Okay, my ideia was to show that $(S+T)^{*}(S+T)=(S+T)(S+T)^*$ so

$(S+T)^*(S+T)=S*S+S*T+T*S+T*T $

$(S+T)(S+T)^*=S^*S+S^*T+T^*S+T^*T $

my doubt is why can i assume that if $T$ comute with $S$ and $T$ is normal then $T$ comute with $S^*$. Anyone could prove this to me?

Comment: What $U$ has to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the approaches given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675239/ab-ba-implies-abt-bta/675267#675267).  Ultimately, you'll need something like either Schur triangularization or the spectral theorem for normal operators.

The fastest approach that builds on top of your work so far is as follows: it suffices to note (using the spectral theorem) that there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $S^* = p(S)$.  From there, it follows that $TS^* = S^*T$.