# normal operator interchangeable then its adjoint also interchangeable

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators, normal-operator

Let $\phi$ be a normal operator on the dimension $n$ Euclidean space, $\psi$ is a linear operator. If $\phi \psi=\psi \phi$, then $\phi^* \psi = \psi \phi^*$, where $\phi^*$ is the adjoint of $\phi$.

I only know I should use then normal condition $\phi \phi^*=\phi^* \phi$, but don't know how. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are to get a quick proof, it is essential that we exploit the finite dimension of the space.  The more general statement is known as [Fugelde's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede%27s_theorem).

One proof (using the spectral theorem) is presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/675239/81360).  In short: because of the spectral theorem, we may deduce that there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $\phi^* = p(\phi)$. The rest is easy.